# Python: Writing to a file and reading it back out

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-io

I am saving a dictionary of student names as keys and grades lists as values. I am attempting to write the values to a file. At the moment I am writing them as strings.

```
def save_records(students, filename):
    #saves student records to a file
    out_file = open(filename, "w")
    for x in students.keys():
        out_file.write(x + " " + str(students[x]) + "\n")
    out_file.close()
```

After saving the file, I try to read it back. The pertinent part of the read out is below.

```
while True:
    in_line = in_file.readline()
    if not in_line:
        break
    #deletes line read in
    in_line = in_line[:-1]
    #initialize grades list
    in_line = in_line.split()
    name = in_line[0]
    students[name] = map(int, in_line[1:])
```

The read out code works well for normal text files that are pre-formatted. The format of the textfile is: key (whitespace) values separated by whitespace "\n". I would like to know how to write in to a text file by combining string and list elements.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "I would like to know how to write in to a text file by combining string and list elements."  Can you explain?  It seems like your algorithm is working but you want to make it "better".  Am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

If you have control over writing the data, I would recommend using a well-established format, such as JSON or INI. This would allow you to make use of common libraries, such as the [json](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) or [ConfigParser](http://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html) modules, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Would it not be easier to use something like pythons [pickle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) which is for storing things like `dicts`

...and then pretty print output to a separate file?

It's hard to say without knowing how you plan on using this...

Answer (score 1):

Since `students[name] = map(int, in_line[1:])`, i assume you want to print the items of the list `student[x]` with whitespaces inbetween.

You could use the [str.join](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) method

```
' '.join(map(str,students[x]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using Comma Separated Value files (aka csv files) instead of plain text files, as these provide a more structured way to read and write your data. Once written, you can open them in a spreadsheet program like Excel to view and edit their contents.

Re-writing your functions to work with csv files, and assuming you are using Python 2.x, we get something like:

```
import csv

def save_records(students, filename):
    # note that csv files are binary so on Windows you
    # must write in 'wb' mode; also note the use of `with`
    # which ensures the file is closed once the block is 
    # exited.
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        # create a csv.writer object
        csv_out = csv.writer(f)
        for name, grades in students.iteritems():
           # write a single data row to the file
           csv_out.writerow([name]+grades)

def read_records(filename):
    students = dict()
    # note that we must use 'rb' to read in binary mode
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        # create a csv.reader object
        csv_in = csv.reader(f)
        for line in csv_in:
            # name will have type `str`
            name = line[0]
            grades = [int(x) for x in line[1:]]
            # update the `students` dictionary
            students[name] = grades
    return students
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use the [csv](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module in the python standard library to read and write .csv files?

Comment: @SethMMorton: that's what I've used, but you may have read my post mid-edit, before I put in the import statement?

Comment: Yup, that must have been what happened, because when I saw it, it wasn't there.